# Migrating drupal users to firebase auth

Tags: firebase, drupal, firebase-authentication, drupal-8

I am attempting to migrate users from Drupal 8 into firebase auth.

I have tried following the instructions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_md5_sha_and_pbkdf_hashed_passwords.

The users import successfully, but the password does not work when I attempt to log in. After reversing the Drupal code, I'm getting the feeling that the sha512 hashing mechanism provided by firebase is not doing the same steps as what drupal does to determine the hash of the password.

The data in the drupal database for one user (this is dev data, not real user)
password: $S$EF//ORKHHZKG9L4UEUUNycm0v5HatfjQxkxbKn19BiYMsPxi3u68

From reading through the drupal code, I've determined the following

$S$ = SHA512

"E" = 16 rounds

"F//ORKH" = the salt

"HZKG9L4UEUUNycm0v5HatfjQxkxbKn19BiYMsPxi3u68" = the hash

This was taken from here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Password%21PhpassHashedPassword.php/class/PhpassHashedPassword/8.7.x

The relevant Go code for the import:

```golang
  users := []*auth.UserToImport{
    (&auth.UserToImport{}).
    UID("00048ebbb178d47f674f48485205235c").
    Email("CPIZFTPX@mailinator.com").
    PasswordHash([]byte("HZKG9L4UEUUNycm0v5HatfjQxkxbKn19BiYMsPxi3u68")).
    PasswordSalt([]byte("F//ORKH")),
  }

  h := hash.SHA512{
    Rounds: 16,
  }

  result, err := client.ImportUsers(context.Background(), users, auth.WithHash(h))
```

So... with all of that said, i think the issue is that the drupal code is truncating the string that is actually being stored in the database to 55 characters. You can see this in the last line of the `crypt` method in the drupal code (url pasted above).

Has anyone out there successfully migrated drupal 8 users to firebase? If so, I'd love to know what step im missing. If not, some confirmation of my findings would help with my sanity.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I've got a similar problem importing from Drupal 7 to auth0 and there are two issues. Firstly the base64 encode is different as you spotted. I've created a base64 decode for Drupal which you can use to reverse this and then re-encode. Secondly Drupal iterates the hash function and if firebase doesn't support this it isn't going to work at all. My decode function is here if it helps: https://gist.github.com/jcable/0ab3728843837991278cc3c063567690.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at this, It doesn't look like that is a SHA. Most systems encode the Bytes of the SHA into a string for ease of storage. Looking at the Drupal code file you posted, it looks like they base64 encode the SHA.

In this case, I believe it needs to be decoded before being passed into `PasswordHash`

Try adding:

```
decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("HZKG9L4UEUUNycm0v5HatfjQxkxbKn19BiYMsPxi3u68")
```

Then just pass it into the rest of your code:

```
  users := []*auth.UserToImport{
    (&auth.UserToImport{}).
    UID("00048ebbb178d47f674f48485205235c").
    Email("CPIZFTPX@mailinator.com").
    PasswordHash(decoded).
    PasswordSalt([]byte("F//ORKH")),
  }

  h := hash.SHA512{
    Rounds: 16,
  }

  result, err := client.ImportUsers(context.Background(), users, auth.WithHash(h))
```

I don't know what the password is, or I would have tested it out on my firebase account.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I think your suggestion is correct, but it unfortunately still doesn't solve the issue of the hash being truncated to 55 characters by drupal before being stored in the database.

Comment: That code just returns a Bool. hashed passwords should never be truncated. I did notice something upon looking at the drupal code again and it actually Base64 encodes the salt and adds it to the end...  I'm not an Auth expert but usually, the salt is added to the beginning of the password before it is hashed. in this case, drupal added after. so just don't send in a salt, and remove it before base64 decoding the hash.

last week I ran into similar issues when adding users to Firebase from my rails app, but my 10 year-ago self made a mistake by adding the salt to the end.

Comment: Thats not returning a bool. see the comments on the method:

`@return string
   *   A string containing the hashed password (and salt) or FALSE on failure.
   *   The return string will be truncated at HASH_LENGTH characters max.`